# Compare array differences by key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two arrays with similar values, but arranged in different keys, example:

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var array2 = [3, 2, 1, 4, 5];
```

They are equal in value, but not in key order. Other questions already address they are equal value.

How do I get the result `array1 != array2` with JavaScript or jQuery based solely on the key order?

Comment: What's your desired output in this case? Do you want `[0,2]`, since those indexes don't match?

Comment: Technically, they are equal.

Comment: They are equal in value, but not in the key order, that's the difference I'm trying to obtain.